# Compute the double Hodge star operator

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I am taking a course in Multivariable Analysis and I am asked to do the following problem:

Show that  $\ast\ast\omega = (-1)^{k(n-k)}\omega$

So I start as follows:

We know that $\displaystyle \ast\omega =\sum_I \text{sgn}(I,J)\omega_I dx^J$ then

$\ast\ast\omega=\sum_I \text{sgn}(I,J)(\sum_I \text{sgn}(I,J)\omega_I dx^J)dx^J$

but I dont know how to rearrange this to avoid the sums and get the result because I think I need to have some wedges products there, but well I dont know how to proceed, I have already read the other questions about this topic, but they are very advanced so I decided to post it with my definition.

Can you help me with this please? Thanks a lot :) in advance for your help.

**My other attempt:**

We can write the operator like this:

$\ast\omega= \ast [\sum_I \omega_I dx^I] = \sum_I \omega_I \ast (dx^I) = \sum_I \omega_I dx^J $

where $dx^J$ is a (n-k)-form so what it remains to be proven is the following:

$$\ast \ast \omega= \ast[ \sum_I \omega_I \ast (dx^I)] = \sum_I \omega_I \ast \ast dx^I $$.

then $(-1)^{k(n-k)}dx^I=\ast \ast dx^I$

this is $\text{sgn}(I,J)\text{sgn}(J,I)=(-1)^{k(n-k)}$

but how  can I do that? and Am I right in the above arguments?

Thanks

Comment: There are some computations that are better done in coordinates. Therefore, I suggest using the usual basis $\mathbb{d}x_{i_1} \wedge \mathbb{d}x_{i_2} \wedge \cdots \wedge \mathbb{d}x_{i_k}$ in which computations can be carried out explicitly.

Comment: How is that, well can you post the computations please? thanks :)

Comment: Think of $u=e_{1} \wedge \ldots \wedge e_{k}$ , where $e_{1} \ldots e_{k}$ are orthonormal . What are both $*u$ and $**u$?

Comment: Right, I have already write it in my post, but The thing is to compute the multiplication of the sgn in the above cycles (I,J) and (J,I) :)

Comment: Thanks @Autolatry but, do you see in what problem does the above one has changed?